# How to recover files and directories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, data-recovery

I used following command to delete all directories except the latest one:

rm -r `ls -t | awk 'NR>1'`

I accidently used the above command on wrong path and deleted many directories from that folder.

If I have to recover all files or directories deleted by this operation what should I do?
Also, if I ran the above command multiple times, is it possible to recover all the files deleted in every execution of command. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have backups? Are they in the Rubbish Bin?

Comment: I am not sure if I have a backups. But they are definitely not in Trash.